# Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich, when updating MacTeX

Tags: texlive, mactex, kpathsea

I was trying to update my MacTeX this afternoon. However, TeX Live Utility complained that it couldn't find TeX Live root using `kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT`. I checked this in the Terminal, and `kpsewhich` worked well. (see the screenshot below) I had also checked other mirrors of CTAN, but the problem went on.

> [image]

System version:

- Mac OS X: 10.9.5
- MacTeX: 2014

Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `sudo tlmgr update --self` at the Terminal help? If so, this is a 'known issue'.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you Joseph, It does help. Could you please explain it for me? (May be a link to the answer)

Comment: See the dupe I've linked: one of those 'passing issues'.